# Dynamic condition with values in the array

Tags: php

I want to generate a dynamic condition with values in the array `$unique_keys`

```php
$unique_keys = array('name', 'phone');
```

And the result in PHP will be :

```
if($search_array['name'] == $current_array['name'] && $search_array['phone'] == $current_array['phone']){
    // some code
}
```

The only way i know it's a foreach and an eval, but there's no cleaner way, something likes [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need `eval` or variable variables? You can use just key names.

```
$unique_keys = array('name', 'phone');
...

$good = true;
foreach ($unique_keys as $k) {
  if ($search_array[$k] != $current_array[$k]) {
    $good = false;
    break;
  }
}

if ($good) {
  // Found!
} else {
  // No luck
}
```